# SQL Merge Statement Assistance

Tags: sql, database, merge, automation, sql-server-2017

[image]Good afternoon,

I'm trying to do a SQL merge with a few steps before this one.

1. Drop Temp Table (If it exists)
2. Create a temp table (Source)

   `USE Kronos Create table #tempGlobal --Source  ( [800#] [bigint] NOT NULL, [FirstName] [varchar](20) NOT NULL, [MI] CHAR(20) NULL, [LastName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL, [NickName] CHAR(15) NULL, [Position] [nvarchar](50) NULL, [Department] [varchar](30) NULL, [EmployeeStatus] [char](20) NOT NULL, [CredentialDocument] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, [RehireDate] [date] NULL, [DateHired] [date] NOT NULL, [DateTerminated] [date] NULL)`
3. Bulk insert from CSV into the temp table
4. Merge source table and target table

I don't get any job errors, but the data doesn't get updated in my test sessions.

Step 4:

```
`      Select t.[800#], t.[FirstName], t.[MI], t.[LastName], t.[NickName], t.[Position],                   t.[Department], t.[EmployeeStatus], t.[CredentialDocument], t.[RehireDate], t.[DateHired], t.[DateTerminated]
        From [dbo].[Employees] t --Target
        Merge [dbo].[Employees] t
        using [dbo].[#tempGlobal] s --Source Temp Table
        on t.[800#] = s.[800#] --Stays the same even if rehired
        WHEN MATCHED 
        AND 
        ( 
        s.[LastName] <> t.[LastName]
        OR s.[Position] <> t.[Position]
        OR s.[Department] <> t.[Department]
        OR s.[EmployeeStatus] <> t.[EmployeeStatus]
        OR s.[RehireDate] <> t.[RehireDate]
        OR s.[DateTerminated] <> t.[LastName]
        )
        THEN
        UPDATE SET LastName = s.LastName,
        Position = s.Position,
        Department = s.Department,
        EmployeeStatus = s.EmployeeStatus,
        RehireDate = s.RehireDate,
        DateTerminated = s.DateTerminated

        WHEN NOT MATCHED --Source table doesn't match target table so we need to update the target     table to match
        THEN INSERT 
        (
        [800#], 
        [FirstName],
        [MI], 
        [LastName], 
        [NickName],
        [Position],
        [Department],
        [EmployeeStatus],
        [CredentialDocument],
        [RehireDate], 
        [DateHired], 
        [DateTerminated])
        VALUES 
        (
        s.[800#],
        s.FirstName,
        s.MI,
        s.LastName,
        s.NickName,
        s.Position,
        s.Department,
        s.EmployeeStatus,
        s.CredentialDocument,
        s.RehireDate,
        s.DateHired,
        s.DateTerminated);`
```

Comment: The MERGE looks fine.  Can you add the code where you generate and populate `#tempGlobal`?  Also, have you confirmed that the temp table is actually populated after the bulk insert?

Comment: The #tempGlobal does populate. If I run the merge by itself I get this:

(1064 row affected)
Msg 241, Lvel 16, State 1, Line 28
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Completion time: blah blah

Comment: You can edit your question to include that information.  It's better that way since it'll format better than a comment.

Comment: Looks like you have an issue in the date format string somewhere while converting it to a SQL Server DATE column.  Please add some sample data from your source CSV file.

Comment: I got it figured out. This is incorrect in the code
 OR s.[DateTerminated] <> t.[LastName]